# php base64_decode strange output

Tags: php, base64

I have a very strange output from base64_decode function. The output is a string with length of 18, however when I var_dump the string .. the length is 32!
This affects the preg_match function that I'm applying for this string.
Any idea why?

```
$input_line = base64_decode('OQA3ADgAMAA5ADgAMgA3ADQAMwA2ADAANwA5ADAAMAAwADAA');
var_dump($input_line);
```

Output

```
string(36) "978098274360790000"
```

Regards

Comment: There's probably unprintable characters in there, e.g. nuls. if you iterate over each character of `$input_line` and print out the ascii value of each char, you'll find where they're hiding.. probably at the end of the string.

Comment: If you force a datatype then does vardump still produce the same result? `var_dump($input_line(int));`

Answer (score 4):

The string has a lot of non-printable characters (the NUL byte).  You can see this by piping the value through a program like `xxd`:

```
0000000: 3900 3700 3800 3000 3900 3800 3200 3700  9.7.8.0.9.8.2.7.
0000010: 3400 3300 3600 3000 3700 3900 3000 3000  4.3.6.0.7.9.0.0.
0000020: 3000 3000                                0.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone especially @tim-cooper
There are null bytes in the string and I found the solution here:
[How can I remove the NULL character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642438/how-can-i-remove-the-null-character-from-string)

so basically:

```
str_replace("\0", "", $input_line);
```