# string compare 2 different lengths

Tags: php, saml-2.0, php-7

I am trying to compare strings but I always get false. I tried to use var_dump on both values but they are 2 different lengths. I have seen this question has been asked many times but not sure how to resolve this.

```
$nameid = $as->getAuthData('saml:sp:NameID');
$luser = $nameid;

$loguser = strtolower($luser);
var_dump($loguser);
// this returns string(167) "test1.test@comtest.com"
$arr = array('test1.test@comtest.com', 'test2.test@comtest.com');

 foreach ($arr as $value) 
 {
    var_dump($value);
    //this returns string(28) "test1.test@comtest.com"
    if ($test == $value)
    {
       echo('success');
       break;
     }        
 }
```

I see this following markup in the View Source: I am not sure how do to get this value from this XML.

```
<saml:nameid xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:assertion" format="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:nameid-format:transient">test1.test@comtest.com</saml:nameid>
```

Comment: *"I have seen this question has been asked many times"* - It might be a good idea to link to one of those places, so we can help you interpret the answers there instead of having to write it from scratch (or close it as duplicate).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642438/how-can-i-remove-the-null-character-from-string/642475#642475

Comment: also tried strcmp() function

Comment: I see the following XML elements in the view source. string(167) "<saml:nameid xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:assertion" format="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:nameid-format:transient">test1.test@comtest.com</saml:nameid>"

Comment: Well, there is your problem. `<saml:nameid xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:assertion" format="urn:oasis:names:tc:saml:2.0:nameid-format:transient">test1.test@comtest.com</saml:nameid>` !== `test1.test@comtest.com`